# Where can I Download API 17 android 4.2?

Tags: android, sdk, download, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I need to download API 17 android 4.2, I'm searching in google but i cant find it. I dowloaded the last version KITKAT but I dont like it because I new in android and all examples in the internet use 4.0 or 4.2 versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can find the ADT here:  http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: I still have the folder...if u have a sftp site, I can share it w/ u.

Comment: sorry, I just checked and the folder is for 4.3, not 4.2... :S

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com is a good starting point. To download code for a special api version you can use the SDK Manger which is included in the sdk/adt download.

Comment: When i use the last SDK my project extends ActionBarActivity and its so complicated to me :(

Comment: If you are using eclipse with the adt plugin you can create a new project without actionbaractivity by selection theme:"none" in the "New Android Application" dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Execute Android SDK MANAGER and select version 4.2.2 (API 17). This will download and install. You can check in your android-sdk/system-images/android-17